# PHP Performance wrapped if statment

Tags: php

I saw this is a code where is loop for payment, there are 5 type of payment 1,2,3,4,5 for 3 of them is generated custom span element. My question is there any point to wrap them in one if statment and if is true only then to check other statment or it is same ?

```
if ($value['payment_code'] == '1' || $value['payment_code'] == '2' || $value['payment_code'] == '3') {

  if ($value['payment_code'] == '1') {
    $order_type = ' <span class="text-danger"> Payment - PP</span>';
  }elseif ($value['payment_code'] == '2') {
    $order_type = ' <span class="text-danger"> Payment PL</span>';
  }elseif ($value['payment_code'] == '3') {
    $order_type = ' <span class="text-danger"> Payment PR</span>';
  }

}
```

OR

```
  if ($value['payment_code'] == '1') {
    $order_type = ' <span class="text-danger"> Payment - PP</span>';
  }elseif ($value['payment_code'] == '2') {
    $order_type = ' <span class="text-danger"> Payment PL</span>';
  }elseif ($value['payment_code'] == '3') {
    $order_type = ' <span class="text-danger"> Payment PR</span>';
  }
```

Comment: No, there is no point in wrapping it (with current code). Unless there is some code that is performed when code is one of `1`/`2`/`3`

Comment: You could in the first case factor out the boiler plate html and after all the `if/else` have something like `$order_type = ' <span class="text-danger"> '.$order_type.'</span>';`

Comment: If this is the only content in the outer `if` then I see no point in it. Only if there's something else in there which you haven't shown, then it depends on what that is

Comment: a switch case statement looks better for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything, something like this would make sense:

```
$codes = ['1' => 'Payment - PP', '2' => 'Payment PL', '3' => 'Payment PR'];

if (isset($codes[$value['payment_code']])) {
    $order_type = "<span ...>{$codes[$value['payment_code']]}</span>";
}
```

Your first approach with the redundant `if` checks is certainly no improvement and only makes things even more repetitive. *Performance* is of extremely little concern here; worry about it when you have proven that something is a bottleneck. This kind of comparison statement will almost certainly never be a bottleneck worth worrying about.